# How to interact sql database in vb.net desktop application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am writing a desktop database application. I want my application to use SQL database. What is the best way to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a database to your project, e.g. a SQL Compact file, or a SQL Server Express file.

But remember: your client needs the drivers, and for the SQL Server Express they need to install the engine.

I would recommend SQL Compact, small, fast, and 99% change you don't need more features than that.

How to start? I would suggest adding that database and then start reading on ADO.NET or the Entity Framework. That should provide you with some brain crunching examples.

Good luck!